# How can I select elements with a class using getElementsByClassName and click them?

Tags: javascript, class, html

I cant seem to click all of the elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('node closed')[0].click();
```

This works but will only click on the first element. I need this to click all of the elements with class 'node closed'.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`[0]` means only the first element of the node list returned by `getElementsByClassName`.

You have to do `getElementsByClassName` and iterate through all the matched elements like shown below:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('node closed');
for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
    el[i].click();
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/7kNGq/)

Comment: I tried this but i just get the error: TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'click'

Comment: Yes, sorry I was about to edit my post. The click method wouldnt work on a node list. you have to iterate through all elements returned from the node list.

Comment: This works but doesnt seem to activate them all. <span class="node closed" onclick="doExpandCollapse(this)"></span> is there a way of activating that onclick event?

Comment: @MaxPort Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/7kNGq/). I have modified it to suit your structure. The `onclick` function is coded to print the `id` of the element to the console log.

Answer (score 3):

iterate the result in a loop and assign click to each elements:

```
var list=document.getElementsByClassName('node closed')
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
list[i].click()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

document.getElementsByClassName has some issues in IE

use jquery

```
window.onload=function(){

$(.yourclass).each(function(){

 $(this).trigger('click');

});

}
```

Answer (score -3):

just remove [0] and it will access all matched elements as [0] points to first element only.

Comment: Maybe in jQuery, but not in vanilla JS.

Comment: In that case, question was supposed be more descriptive. And solution provided is as per the normal logic applied in javascript for indexing elements.

Comment: jQuery objects have that "normal logic", but not [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)s returned by `getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score -3):

```
$(".node closed").filter(function() {
    return $(this).click();
});
```