# How can i perform a mouse click on a node/nodes in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I want to perform a mouse click on a node in the Dom

I've tried a straight up click on the node but i didn't get any click.

```
var events = document.getElementsByClassName("class name");    
var choose = document.getElementsByClassName("class name");   
// choose is the element i need to click on
click('choose');
```

I did not get any click on any element(s)
[undefined element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STke7.png)

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784763/select-all-classs-with-getelementsbyclassname-and-click

Comment: Thank you,i have seen it.Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event using dispatchEvent

```
document.querySelectorAll(".classname").forEach(function(element){
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });

element.dispatchEvent(evt)

})
```

Comment: Thank you Somesh,i'm about to try it out.

Comment: Thank you,i'm about to.

Comment: unexpected token:identifier

Comment: i have posted it.